# Google Analytics iOS SDK, very long dispatch interval

Tags: ios, iphone, google-analytics, intervals, dispatch

I've integrated Google Analytics iOS SDK in my iOS App, I want to set a long dispatch interval to avoid frequent network calls.  I want to set 6 hours or longer interval.

```
  // set Google Analytics dispatch interval, eg: 20 seconds
    [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 6*60*60; // dispatch after every 6 hours
```

I have few queries:

**Q1.** What will happen if App is killed just before the data is dispatched, will data be sent immediately when app is launched next time? (eg: app killed just few minutes before the dispatch interval).

**Q2.** Let's suppose app tries to dispatch data after 6 hours but network is not available at that time. will data be dispatched again after next 6 hours as aggregate of 12 hours data?

Any suggestion for optimised approach? I don't want to consume network bandwidth after every few seconds or minutes just for minor data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

dispatchInterval default is 120 (2 min).

Did you send a lot of datas?  If you have vital datas, I suggest to keep it as 120(or better).  As it use very minimal bandwidth.

If you are offline, the data will be sent when you are online again. (use event to test it easily in your app)

According to Google.:
Data collected using the Google Analytics SDK for iOS is stored locally before being dispatched on a separate thread to Google Analytics.

If a user loses network access or quits your app while there are still hits waiting to be dispatched, those hits are persisted in local storage. They will be dispatched the next time your app is running and dispatch is called.

More info here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/dispatch

Comment: Thanks for answering question.  the data is not vital at all, as it is just for analysing different events and if it is dispatched once in a day then it's also fine for me. i need to analyse app analytics weekly or monthly so difference of few hours or 1 day doesn't matter.  i was just more interested to avoid unnecessary network calls after every few minutes....

Comment: you can choose to set the default dispatchInterval to 0, this forces GA not to upload any data and you can do manual dispatch by calling dispatch() method whenever you want.

Another better way is to dispatch in the background, read manual dispatch - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/dispatch